# Stackoverflow error in Visual Studio with C# and XNA . How to inspect the stack?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, stack-overflow

I have a stackoverflow problem with a C# application written using Visual Studio 2010 and XNA library. My application keep increasing memory usage until it crashes for a stackoverflow.

I would like to inspect the stack to understand where is the bug, but I don't know how to do this using VS 2010.

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

Comment: doesn't the Stack window of Visual Studio shows you what's happen ?

Comment: I can see the stacktrace when the program crashes, but I don't know (I'm a VS newbie) how to find what is consuming it. (And I don't remember to have used recursion anywhere, so I don't think it's a recursive function related problem)

Comment: Try find out recursive method or property calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the debugger prior to the problem (or start the application under the debugger)

Then, the easiest way to find your stack overflow is to set the debugger to stop on that exception when thrown; which can be done from the "Exceptions" window (with my keybindings, this can be brought up with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, but also found under the "Debug" menu).

Once stopped, you can use the Stack trace debug window to spy the repeating call that is causing the stack to overflow.

Comment: Stack trace debug window can be opened with ctrl + d, c

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
You need to check for recursive method calls.